# Нужна ли запятая после "может"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "может": *"Хорошо, может ты и прав"?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Хорошо, может, ты и прав.***

***Хорошо, может ты и прав.***

Вариант немного нестандартный.

1)  С одной стороны, **по Розенталю**,  вводное слово  на границе двух предложений обособляется, и обычно пользователи следуют этому правилу. С другой стороны, предложение короткое, а запятых получается много.

2) **Если обратиться к правила ПАС,** то там вводное слово не обособляется:

§ 94. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, **не отделяются от него запятой** (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения): Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.). http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127

3) Можно использовать это правило, но надо бы определить вид предложения. БСП? Наверное, только вот первая часть (слово *хорошо*)  в словаре отнесли к частицам.IV. частица. 1. Согласен, да, пусть будет так.

Поэтому у автора есть возможность выбора.

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятая нужна. ***Может*** здесь *вводное слово,* сокращённая форма от ***может быть***. Это не член предложения, хотя бы исходя из согласования, точнее, его отсутствия (должно быть *ты може**шь***).

> Хорошо, может, ты и прав.